# How to conditionally pass values to django's queryset.values

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I have a HTML form that is being submitted to a django view via get method. The goal is to print a list of users from the users table but only print the fields that have been selected in the form i.e. the user will select the columns that they want to print.

In my View, I check to see if a given column is selected then append it to a list. I then pass this list to django's queryset.values() method. However, it does not accept a list object as an argument.

```
class PrintUsers(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'users/print-users.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        context = super(PrintUsers, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        users_list = Member.objects.all()

        values_list = []

        if self.request.GET.get('category') == 'on':
            values_list.append("category")

        if self.request.GET.get('email') == 'on':
            values_list.append("email")

        users_list.values(values_list) # this does not work

        context['users_list'] = users_list

        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)
```

How can I conditionally build the *fields values as the documentation does not explain this here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values ??

Comment: I mean, you kinda pointed it out in your OP: it should be `values(*values_list)`. The asterisk unpacks the list into positional arguments for the function.

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform you're right. That appears to work. I must have missed that class when learning python. Merci beaucoup.